# html <select> event handler onfocus

Tags: html, event-handling

Tested with Internet explorer 7 (for backwards compatibility) and Firefox 4.
I am getting strange behaviour from select event handler.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp states that event handlers supported.

```
<select id="selection" onfocus="window.status='here';" 
  onblur="window.status='there';"> 
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

I cannot get any event handler to respond through the select tag. Am I doing something wrong? is the select event handler not firing or?
any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `window.status`.

> The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE,
>   Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. To allow scripts to change the text of the
>   status, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change
>   preference to false in the about:config screen. (or in Firefox: "Tools
>   - Options - Content -Enable JavaScript / Advanced - Allow scripts to
>   change status bar text").

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp).

Comment: But I have other scripts that will do the window.status. Hence this is not the problem. In any event my question is more about just event handling - forget window.status, change to function(); alert('here'); whatever else.

Comment: Ok. Never mind. Its working now? I must be a lunatic. Thanks everyone and stealthyninja!